# Possible abuse of notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

This is probably a very simple question, yet I am very confused.

Whenever, we define a function, we tend to define it in the following way
$$
f: X \rightarrow Y \quad \quad x \mapsto f(x).
$$
So far so good. However, we sometimes like to change the notation  and this is what really confuseses me.

Example of confusion:

Consider
$$
f: R \rightarrow R \quad \quad x \mapsto x.
$$
A lot of books would write this as $f(x)=x$. Say now, because of some reason, we wanted $t^3=x$. How would we write this with our function? I have seen both of

- $$f(t)=t^3$$
- $$f(x)= t^3$$

In my opinion, the later is correct. I have seen people justify the first, in applied settings because $f$ is a function of $t$, but yet it doesn't make sense from the definition.

**Question 1:** Which is correct?

**Question 2:** Say we wanted to solve some differential equation
$$
\mathcal{L}f=0
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is differential operator. If say we solve this in cartesian coordinates, we would solve it and write
$$
f(x,y,z)= \Gamma(x,y,z),
$$
for some $\Gamma(x,y,z)$.
Now say we worked in spherical polars. Then, we would instead solve and write our solution as
$$
f(r,\theta,\phi)= \Omega(r,\theta,\phi).
$$
Is it true then that if we invert our coordinates we should get that $\Gamma(x,y,z)=\Omega(r,\theta, \phi)$? Moreover, is what I have written above abuse of notation as really $r,\theta, \phi$ are not the inputs but rather we should have had, for both,
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\Gamma(x,y,z) \text{  and  } f(\mathbf{x})=\Omega(r,\theta,\phi)?
$$
I think that this is true as then we wont have issues equating both sides and getting nonsense like $x=r,y=\theta,z=\phi$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $f(x)=x$ and $x=t^3$, why would $f(x)=t^{1/3}$?  Did you mean to write $f(x)=t^3$?  But that seems much less informative than just writing $f(x)=x, x=t^3$.  If nothing else, writing $t^{1/3}$ means choosing a branch for the cube root.

Comment: Apologies, I have now corrected it.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.  If $f(x)=x$, by definition, then $f(t)=t$.  I suppose you could write $f(x)=x, f(x)=t^3$ but it still seems far less informative than $f(x)=x, x=t^3$.

Comment: Brevity is certainly a goal in mathematical notation, but it takes a back seat to Clarity, or at least it should.